# access hard disk from ubuntu terminal with label with spaces

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, directory

I have an harddisk with the name(label) SP PHD U3 . How can I access to it with the terminal of ubuntu?
Because when I write:
root@mypc-PC:/media/mypc# cd SP PHD U3

I receive
bash: cd: SP: No such file or directory

How can I solve that problem?

Comment: Either use escapes like `cd SP\ PHD\ U3` or use quotes like `cd "SP PHD U3"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use quotes when accessing directory/file names with spaces. In general it's a bad idea to use space if you are planning on working with a file/directory in a terminal environment. So, your command would be:

`cd "SP PHD U3"`